# Magento programmatically refresh statistics. - Magento1

Tags: magento-1, programmatically, statistics

How to refresh **statistics** programmatically in **Magento 1**?

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom php file at root level and use below code

```
<?php

    require_once "app/Mage.php";

    Mage::app();

    umask(0);

    ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);

    ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');

    set_time_limit(0);

    $row = 0;


    $allcodes = array(

    '0' => 'sales/report_order',

    '1' => 'tax/report_tax',

    '2' => 'sales/report_shipping',

    '3' => 'sales/report_invoiced',

    '4' => 'sales/report_refunded',

    '5' => 'salesrule/report_rule',

    '6' => 'sales/report_bestsellers',

    );



    try 

    {

        foreach ($allcodes as $collectionName) 

        {

            Mage::getResourceModel($collectionName)->aggregate();

            /// print_r($tr);


        }

        Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Lifetime statistics have been updated.'));

    } 

    catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e)

    {


        Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());


    } 

    catch (Exception $e) 

    {

        Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Unable to refresh lifetime statistics.'));

        Mage::logException($e);

    }


?>
```